# How to integrate AAA and otp

Tags: authentication, audit, authorization, one-time-password

We have AAA services enabled in our organization (about 1000 clients). We want also to add otp (one time password) service. What are the main security concerns about integrating them. Is there any available solution (preferably based on Windows Operating System) available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OTP should integrate with your RADIUS server. I guess you are using NPS?
The SafeNet Authentication Manager integrates with NPS and you can use different kind of OTP tokens (preseeded and seedable tokens).

You can seed the eTokenNG OTP, i.e. you write the secrets on the tokens yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please also introduce some (less technical) resources about the architecture we must use. Any white paper or book is appreciated.

Comment: The way to go is use OTP with RADIUS. I published a Howto [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/two-factor-authentication-with-otp-using-privacyidea-and-freeradius-on-centos). It would be the same way with the SafeNet Auth Manager. [privacyIDEA](http://www.privacyidea.org) (which is a linux based open source solution) and the SafeNet Auth Manager both support HOTP and TOTP tokens. While privacyIDEA also supports many other token types like mOTP, RADIUS token, Remote, SMS, Email, OCRA...

Answer (score 0):

There is two standards widely deployed for one-time-passwords: [HOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) (HMAC-based One-time Password, based on an incrementing counter) and [TOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) (Time-based One-time Password, obviously based on time).

The wikipedia page points on some server implementations. Moreover there are numerous clients for HOTP or TOTP technologies (either mobile phone apps or physical tokens)

Comment: We want to choose among a number of proposals. What do we must consider (in less technical aspect)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some PAM hooks that automatically updates the AAA system.

But right, that doesn't exist on a windows system.

Comment: Do you mean there may be a solution on linux? Would you please pass me a reference?